# Bash Array Contains false positives

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to see if a value exists in a bash array. If so, do something. Else, do something else.

I can't figure out why this is always failing for me.

Basically start with two separate values, concatenate them with a delimiter, search against an array and if that entire string (delimiter and all) is in any of the array elements do something, else do something else.

```
#!/bin/bash

FNAME="JACK"
LNAME="BLACK"

SEARCHNAME=()
SEARCHNAME+="JACK-BLACK"
SEARCHNAME+="JOHN-JAMES"
SEARCHNAME+="CHRIS-TOPHER"
SEARCHNAME+="JEN-NAY"

NAME="${FNAME}-${LNAME}"

if [[ $NAME == *"${SEARCHNAME[@]}"* ]]; then
    echo "PASSED"
else
    echo "FAILED"
fi

echo "SEARCH IN: ${SEARCHNAME[@]}"
echo "FOR NAME: ${NAME}"
```

Results:

```
FAILED
SEARCH IN: JACK-BLACKJOHN-JAMESCHRIS-TOPHERJEN-NAY
FOR NAME: JACK-BLACK
```

I've also tried `if [[ "${NAME}" == *"${SEARCHNAME[@]}"* ]]` but no difference... I'm missing something pretty obvious here and am thinking it might be with the way I'm declaring my array? I'd expect the lack of space between each array element (seen in array output) to not make a difference because of the wild-card characters?

Comment: You are not adding array elements, easily checked by adding the line `echo "There are ${#SEARCHNAME[@]} members of the array"` at the end of your script. It will indicate `1` member. The `+=` assignments should look like `SEARCHNAME+=("JACK-BLACK")`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I re-ran but it still is failing?
`#!/bin/bash

FNAME="JACK"
LNAME="BLACK"

SEARCHNAME=()
SEARCHNAME+=("JACK-BLACK")
SEARCHNAME+=("JOHN-JAMES")
SEARCHNAME+=("CHRIS-TOPHER")
SEARCHNAME+=("JEN-NAY")

NAME="${FNAME}-${LNAME}"

if [[ "${NAME}" == *"${SEARCHNAME[@]}"* ]]; then
    echo "PASSED"
else
    echo "FAILED"
fi

echo "SEARCH IN: ${SEARCHNAME[@]}"
echo "FOR NAME: ${NAME}"
echo "ELEMENT COUNT: ${#SEARCHNAME[@]}"`
Results
`FAILED
SEARCH IN: JACK-BLACK JOHN-JAMES CHRIS-TOPHER JEN-NAY
FOR NAME: JACK-BLACK
ELEMENT COUNT: 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the array assignments, and change the test to a regex.

```
#!/bin/bash

FNAME="JACK"
LNAME="BLACK"

SEARCHNAME=()
SEARCHNAME+=("JACK-BLACK")
SEARCHNAME+=("JOHN-JAMES")
SEARCHNAME+=("CHRIS-TOPHER")
SEARCHNAME+=("JEN-NAY")

NAME="${FNAME}-${LNAME}"

if [[ "${SEARCHNAME[@]}" =~ $NAME ]]; then
    echo "PASSED"
else
    echo "FAILED"
fi

echo "SEARCH IN: ${SEARCHNAME[@]}"
echo "FOR NAME: ${NAME}"
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my poor syntax! Also, I guess I've been using the comparitor wrong for a while now. If I leave it without regex, but swap the spots so it's 
`if [[  "${SEARCHNAME[@]}" == *"${NAME}"* ]];`
it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd still use the regex `=~` method in my answer over the `==` test.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to note here:

1. Using the `==` in place of `=~` as we"re not looking for equality here.
2. Since this is a `regex` not `wildcard` so ...
3. The order of operands in the [[ needs to be reversed, viz., like as:

   ```
   if [[ ${SEARCHNAME[@]} =~ .*$NAME.* ]]
   ```